# How can I stop my text array from flashing and switching in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, awt

I am having a problem with my text array, the text keeps switching constantly. This is the code that I have so far for it:

```
private void drawSplash(Graphics2D g) {
  if (displayed == false) {
     Random r = new Random();
     String list;
     String items[] = { "Buggy!", "New Game!", "Roll up, roll up!",
           "Made from Scratch" };
     int amount;
     amount = (int) (Math.random() * 25 + 1);
     list = items[r.nextInt(3 + 1)];
     System.out.println(list);
     g.setFont(font2);
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.drawString(list, 320, 240);
     displayed = true;
  }
}
```

I want to make it so that whenever the program is restarted, the string change.

Can anyone help me with this please? It's really bugging me.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I guess `drawSplash` is called within the `paint` method. You are explicitly using `Random` to display random text, so obviously, you are ending up with flashy, constantly changing text.

Comment: My first intuition is that wherever this method is being called, is being called so that it continues to drawSplash. So it will keep showing a new text everytime. Also when you call g.drawString, the list calls a different item than the System.out.println

Comment: So, how would I go about getting around that? @ortis

Comment: @ConnorWright Depends, when *do* you want one of the other strings to appear?

Comment: Again -- You've got to show more pertinent code, preferably compilable, preferably **short**. Please read the link that I've given you.

Comment: @owlstead I want to make it so that whenever the program is restarted, the string changes

Comment: You should make a `static` and `final` variable then.

Comment: Why do you need `amount` variable ?

Comment: @Kao I accidentally left that there whilst I was trying to resolve it, I have now removed it.

Comment: and now, it just prints to the console and not the program itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels here is the full class code: http://pastebin.com/Sf9am9An

Comment: That is the code that is causing the trouble @HovercraftFullOfEels, the one that I posted in the OP, all I have in the other classes referring to that is a GameStateManager, which checks if the menu is clicked, and then creates a new instance of the menu state, which I am trying to fix now.

Comment: @ConnorWright: your code is too complex to lay all the blame on the code above. If the code above were called only once, then that would solve your problem, but its not, but how it's called is anyone's guess because one can't tell based on the code above or the code in your link. You will want to refactor your code I think to make it easier to manage and debug.

Comment: What refactoring do I need to do to it?

Comment: Change your program structure to conform to one of the MVC design pattern variants would be a great start, I think. As to your problem, you're putting program logic -- randomization of display -- within a painting method, and you should not do that. If you had decent MVC separation, this would never be an issue.

Comment: Note that MVC stands for Model-View-Control, where you try to pull all the logical portions of your code, the brains behind its workings, into the model, all the GUI stuff in to the view, and the user interaction and connection between model and view into the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you want to keep state between program startups, otherwise you will get repeats. So what you want to do is:

During startup: if no property file with a shuffled list exists, create a shuffled list, set index to 1

Then:

1. during startup: retrieve shuffled list and index from property file
2. put the item with the given index in a `static` field
3. increase the index and store the property file again
4. display the item during paint

I'll leave it up to you what you do when you run out of items.

---

For a quick fix that simply displays a random item each time the class is used:

```
private static String ITEMS[] = { "Buggy!", "New Game!",
        "Roll up, roll up!", "Made from Scratch" };

private String itemDisplayed = chooseItem();

private String chooseItem() {
    Random r = new SecureRandom();
    int i = r.nextInt(ITEMS.length);
    return ITEMS[i];
}

private void drawSplash(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(font2);
    g.drawString(itemDisplayed, 320, 240);
    displayed = true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will take some time and code, a bit too much time and code to put into a full answer.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this is due next week as a school assignment.

Comment: Do you really need this part? You can also just make a choice once the program starts up, and put it in a String field of the class named item, then display that field during paint. It will of course randomize each time the class is recreated (and may therefore repeat), but it won't flicker.

Comment: I need this part, yes for a better grade, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry, another edit, removed lazy instantiation (checking against `null` was not necessary).

Comment: I added the displayed boolean because I was trying to stop the flickering.

Comment: and now, when I run it, it just quickly comes up and goes off again

Comment: OK,then you are regenerating the class, make `itemDisplayed` and `chooseItem` both `static`. But beware that this would be a superficial fix; you should really refactor...

Comment: That doesn't work either, it doesn't come up entirely now, should I just ditch the idea?

Comment: What if you remove the `if` statement? As said, I don't know what `displayed` does...

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `static` keyword again - never leave fixes that don't work... Nobody would expect gay love on SO, so that last comment is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is wrong:

```
list = items[r.nextInt(3+1)]
```

Each time `drawSplash()` method is executed,  `list` has a new random value.

You should init it only once:

```
String list;
Random r = new Random();

public void initListIndex(){
     String items[] = { "Buggy!", "New Game!", "Roll up, roll up!",
           "Made from Scratch" };

     int listIndex = r.nextInt(3 + 1);
     list= items[listIndex];
}

private void drawSplash(Graphics2D g) {
  if (displayed == false) {
     System.out.println(list);
     g.setFont(font2);
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.drawString(list, 320, 240);
     displayed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to put `String items[]` into the `initListIndex`, as `items` is saying `cannot be resolved to a variable`?

Comment: And now it says `Type mismatch: cannot convert String to int`

Comment: Make sure your 'list' is of type String.

Comment: It is, I've put it at the top of my class declaration: `String list;`

Comment: No, your `items` array is of type `String[]`, and you're trying to pass the value at a specified index to an `int`. That's not going to work -  you need to make `listIndex` a `String`.

Comment: @TNT, Yes, of course, fixed it. Sorry, I was blind for a moment :)

Comment: Right, that works so far, thank you. Now, I always get stuck with this part:
I want to go to the drawSplash class, I've tried:
`drawSplash(g);` and
`drawSplash();`
Do I just write `drawSplash(Graphics2D);`?

Comment: Oops, forgot to tag you @Kao

Answer (score 0):

I guess drawSplash is called each time the text changes. If you only want to draw a random String on e.g. initialize make a own function for

```
list = items[r.nextInt(3+1)];
```

which gets only called once

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `drawSplash()`, but a) how often it gets called, and b) even if it gets called frequently, then somebody must change the value of `displayed` to `false` outside of the method.
Just some minor comments:

`if (!displayed)` is the usual style

`amount` is never used

`Random r` is not really needed